# Uncaught Error: Call to a member function query() on null

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement, sql-insert

I got stuck for hours in the code below. I don't know how I can fix this error.

> Notice: Undefined variable: mysqli in D:\xampp\htdocs\recon\register.php on line 19
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function query() on null in D:\xampp\htdocs\recon\register.php:19 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in D:\xampp\htdocs\recon\register.php on line 19

```
<?php

$conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'user');

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

$uname = $_POST['uname'];
$psw = $_POST['psw'];
$options = [
'cost' => 12,];
$hashedpassword= password_hash($psw, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, $options);

$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT username FROM registration WHERE username = '$uname'"); 
$row_count = $result->num_rows; 
if($row_count == 1) { 
    echo 'User already exists, try another one.'; } 
else {

    $query = "INSERT INTO user (username, password) VALUES(?, ?)";
    $statement = $mysqli->prepare($query);

    $statement->bind_param('ss', $uname, $hashedpassword);

    if($statement->execute())
    {
         print 'Success! Last inserted record : ' .$statement->insert_id .'<br />'; 
    }
    else
    {
         die('Error : ('. $mysqli->errno .') '. $mysqli->error);
    }
    $statement->close();

}

?>
```

Comment: Where do you define the variable `$mysqli`?  Why *shouldn't* it be `null`?

Comment: So did you follow two different tutorials? $conn vs $mysqli http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php#example-1878

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are declaring instance of `mysqli` called `$conn`. This represents your connection to DB. You should call methods on variable `$conn` and not on (undefined) variable `$mysqli`. So ie. your line 19 should be:

```
$result = $conn->query("SELECT username FROM registration WHERE username = '$uname'")
```

Also to prevent SQL-Injection on your queries/web-pages you should use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) EVERYWHERE(including `SELECT`).

Comment: thank you, that helped me to figure out where I made a mistake.

Answer (score 1):

you get this error if you spell constructor incorrectly. 
For instance, correct syntax of constructor in php,

```
__construct(){}
```

You might have mistakenly written,

```
__contruct(){}
```

Similarly, check for other functions.